# About meat eating and spices in Rama's time

Tags: ramayana, history, rama, food, reference-request

Are spices mentioned in any Puranas / Ramayan used during Rama's time? Specially with respect to sattvik or tamasic nature. What were the dharmic rules about meat eating, about what parts were allowed and how it should be slain and cooked?

Comment: I personally think that the edit changes the question too much. To the OP, if you also feel that way, you can revert it to the original by clicking the revision history and pressing `[rollback]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

[Ramayana 2.91:](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424068.html)

> The men beheld countless dishes of mutton, pork, venison and other meats cooked in fruit-juices and fried in butter with **cloves**, **caraway seeds** and lentils simmering gently in them. Thousands of vessels were filled with spiced rice, garnished with flowers and flags. All were speechless with wonder on beholding them! Within a radius of five miles, the wells were filled with frumenty (khiva) and cows like Kamadhenu fulfilled every desire! The trees dripped honey and the lakes were filled with the sparkling wine Maireya, and banked with dressed viands such as deer, chickens and peacocks. Hundreds and thousands of dishes were provided, and myriads of vessels filled with curds, mixed with caraway seeds, ginger and other **fragrant spices**, were served there.

Comment: thanks. do you think sita was a herbalist? In the forest how did she collect spices?

Comment: @blue_ego - I'm not sure. I can't find any reference to her collecting herbs, spices, etc., so I think they were mostly hunting and collecting berries.